# Disk space StreamWriter vs Out-File

Tags: .net, powershell, text-files, streamwriter, diskspace

When writing to a text file with `.Net` `StreamWriter`, Why does the text file take up less room on disk than when using PowerShell's `Out-File`. The following script creates the same text file with both `StreamWriter` and `Out-File`. But looking at the two text files produced, the 'StreamWriter' text file takes up half the room; why is this?

```
$String = 1..1000

# StreamWriter
$stream5 = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "E:\\Stream.txt"
$String | %{$stream5.WriteLine($_)}
$stream5.Close()

# Out-File
$string | Out-File "E:\Out-file.txt"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Out-File` defaults to `Unicode` encoding.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx) `StreamWriter` defaults to `UTF8` which uses half the space for common western characters.

I guess the designers of `Out-File` made a mistake here and picked an unhelpful default. UTF8 is unicode just like UTF-16 is. Just smaller in many common cases. No functional difference.

Comment: Unicode encoding is neither a mistake nor unhelpful. It takes up more space, but in this age of cheap storage that just isn't primary concern. Microsoft is a global company, and defaulting to an encoding that doesn't support internationalization very well is no longer acceptable. Powershell has been updated to reflect that. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @BillHurt UTF8 is unicode just like UTF-16 is. Just smaller in many common cases. No functional difference. Joel talks about that as well.